# SQLiteAssetHelper - 'No such table' error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have prepopulated a database with DB Browser for SQLite and tried to retrieve data from it using SQLiteAssetHelper (installed and used it using the guide at https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper  ) and got a "No such table" error. I am sure that there is a table named that way in the database. I've tried to debug it and saw that I leave the DATABASE_VERSION as equal to one than it detects that there is already a database and doesn't copy it, though if I change the database version and setForceUpdate to (true) then it copies it, but I get the same error anyway. What should I do for SQLiteAssetHelper to copy my database properly and get rid of that annoying error?

Code:

DataBaseHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DonRoll";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static DataBaseHelper instance;

public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context context){
    if (null == instance){
        instance = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public Cursor getAllCategoryNames() {
    setForcedUpgrade(2);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables("MenuCategories");
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

}

Activity class:

```
public class CategoryListActivity extends ListActivity {

DataBaseHelper db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_list);
    db = DataBaseHelper.getInstance(this);
    getData();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void getData() {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            db.getAllCategoryNames(),
            new String[] { "value" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: What is a forced upgrade. What happens when it is called

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app on your device remains a good way to debug a database since you can be sure that the current one will disappear, you can also remove all the datas linked to the app on the settings.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic What code do you want? The exception happens in public Cursor getAllCategoryNames(), when it makes an SQL query. SQLiteAssetHelper is a library found at https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @haseeb When it is set SQLiteAssetHelper is forced to copy the database from assets even if it already exists in Android app destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I've used `adb pull` to get the database file from the assets folder and it somehow got corrupted - it had only the "android_metadata" table. I don't know why this happened (maybe because I renamed it after I have put it into Android studio?), but once I have deleted this file and replaced it with a proper one everything worked just fine.